# Remove dynamically a iframe from itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm currently developping an overlay and have an issue with it. In fact my overlay is materialized by an iframe that i'm injecting in all the web page.

Overlay : http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/691/toolbarm.png

I would like just hide it when i press on the close button at the right side.

Here is my function that inject the overlay (iframe) :

```
injectOverlay: function() 
{
        var body = $('body'),
        OverlayURL= chrome.extension.getURL("overlay.html"),
        iframe = $('<iframe id="OverlayFrame" scrolling="no" src="'+OverlayURL+'">');

        body.append(iframe);
}
```

And here is the code to hide it (but it didn't work) :

```
function hideOverlay()
{
    var iframe = document.getElementsByName('iframe')[0];
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);

    // $('#OverlayFrame', window.parent.document).remove();

    alert('Overlayclosed');
}
```

Comment: Where is the code running to hide it? Inside the iframe or outside it?

Comment: On a file named Tools.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using jquery anyway, just write

```
var fram = $("iframe").get(0);
fram.parentNode.removeChild(fram);
```

That will only work if you only have 1 iframe on the whole page. Otherwise you could specify the selector in the normal jquery fasion (iframe#id or whatnot).

Comment: try fram.remove(); directly
or even better $("iframe").get(0).remove();

Comment: Are you sure you only have 1 iframe in the page? Try $("iframe#OverlayFrame").get(0) instead.

Comment: Seing even this didn't help it sure seems like you have en error somewhere else in your code. Turn on the console in firebug or whatever, and watch if you get any javascript errors. If there is an error before the code that hides the overlay, it will not be run, as the interpreter stops executing your script after certain kinds of errors.

Comment: Not really because when i execute this :

function hideToolbar()
{ 
 $('iframe#OverlayFrame').remove();

 alert('Toolbar closed');
}

The alert "Toolbar Closed" appear.

Peraps i need to delete the iframe from the parent page ?

Comment: And this one :

var fram = $('iframe').get(0);
 fram.parentNode.removeChild(fram);

 alert('Toolbar closed');

Don't show the alert, it's like it didn't find the iframe.

Comment: Aha, you are running the code from within the iframe page? Then of course, you have to go back to the parent page. I think something like this could work: instead of $('#OverlayFrame'), do a $('#OverlayFrame', document.parent) (i.e. specifying parent as the scope in which jquery should look for the object).

Comment: I've tried with document.parentNode/parentWindow/parentElement. The popup appear but the overlay didn't disapear.

Comment: I've just tried this : $('body', window.parent.document).remove();

But it only delete the body of the iframe, and not of the web page. How can you explain that ? Window.parent.document donc take the main page ?

Comment: window.parent.document in that case is the context in which the jquery will look for your selector. So it will look for body element in the parent document of the document in which you are calling this function.

Comment: Yeah sure, but when i'm executing this "$('#overlayFrame', window.parent.document).remove();" it seems to not find a id with overlayFrame...

Nobody has a suggestion ?

Comment: @sinder have you find the solution of this problem. I am struggling with the same problem. I am creating custom toolbar and injecting it to each webpage using chrome extension. I want to remove this toolbar on click of "not now" button. Please help me if you got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try any of the following options :

```
$("iframe").remove() 
$('#OverlayFrame').remove() 
$('iframe#OverlayFrame').remove()
```

you can use `detach()` / `hide()` instead of remove().

Comment: It's the same. Nothing changed

Comment: @Sindar: Improve your error reporting. What is the console error? What debugging did you apply to this technique to find out what's wrong?

Comment: @Sindar: What, where you wrote "It didn't work :s" ? [edit: ok, there's a bit more there now]

Comment: In fact this code can't work because i'm on the iframe when i execute this. So he didn't find #OverlayFrame. I need to search being out of this iframe...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide it, you dont need to remove it, perhaps

```
jQuery('#OverlayFrame').toggle();
```